# How to conver bin data to int16 in php

Tags: php, c++

I have this code in Qt c++

```
const unsigned char *packed = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data.constData());

res.type = static_cast<int>(packed[0]);
res.period = static_cast<int>(packed[1]);
res.rate = static_cast<qint16>(packed[2] | (packed[3] << 8)) / 100.;
res.edge = static_cast<qint16>(packed[4] | (packed[5] << 8)) / 100.;

return res;
```

How to convert it from c++ to php

I try this:

```
        $a = unpack ("C*", $data);
        $eventList = [];

        for ($i=0; $i < $a[1]; $i++)
        {
                $event = array ();
                $index = $i * 6 + 2;

                $event["type"] = $a[$index];
                $event["period"] = $a[$index+1];
                $event["rate"] = ($a[$index+2] | ($a[$index+3] << 8)) / 100;
                $event["edge"] = ($a[$index+4] | ($a[$index+5] << 8)) / 100;

        }
```

Edge conver wrong
Very big value.
[edge] => 650.86 
must be -4.5

Type, period and rate is good;

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the exact answer but some of possible ways to solve the problem:

1. Check `$a[$index+4]` and `$a[$index+5]` value by using var_dump to get its value and type:

   var_dump($a[$index+4]);
   var_dump($a[$index+5]);

is the data type and its value as expected? Probably good idea is to check as above all data before/after calculation to exactly know what you are dealing with.

2. Double check your conversion type, perhaps you should't use `C*` but other, perhaps `S` or `s`?
   [conversion types](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)
3. If you need type conversion in php you can check how it is done here: [Type Juggling and Casting](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Note that in PHP you can use a string with ASCII digit that can be treated as digit for calculations:

```
$foo = 5 * "10 Little Piggies"; // $foo is integer (50)
```

Which is something you probably don't want.

4. If you expect negative value but you get positive you have problem because your'e not setting MSB by shifting bits:

The MSB can also correspond to the sign bit of a signed binary number
[read-wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most_significant_bit)

in case `packed[5]` should be negative but it isn't

5. If this not helps then provide data sample and expected values for Edge, Type, period and rate.